# How to use groupby in whereHas

Tags: laravel, group-by, wherehas

I have two tables `variants` and `variant_attributes` which have one to many `relation`.

Each `variant` has one or more rows in `variant_attributes` table.

A group of variants could have these

```
[
  1 => [13, 1, 18],
  2 => [13, 2, 18],
  3 => [13, 3, 18],
  4 => [14, 1, 18],
  5 => [14, 2, 18],
  6 => [14, 3, 18],
  7 => [15, 1, 18],
  8 => [15, 2, 18],
  9 => [15, 3, 18]
]

$attribute_id = [1, 13];

$variants->whereHas('variant_arrtibutes', function ($q) use ($attribute_id) {
    $q->whereIn('attribute_value_id', $attribute_id);
});
```

It returns `variants` with IDs `[1, 2, 3, 4, 7]` instead of only `id = 1` as I want.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are checking a `variant` has at least one of the `attributes` you provide. Try:

```php
$variants->whereDoesntHave('variant_arrtibutes', function ($q) use ($attribute_id) {
    $q->whereNotIn('attribute_value_id', $attribute_id);
});
```

Comment: It is not working at all. I thought my be using `groupBy` will help, but I don't know how!